# PHP: What is the origin of the 'type' index in $_FILES?

Tags: php, security, apache, file-upload, webserver

In order to validate allowed mime types in file uploads I usually rely on the [`fileinfo`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension but since that extension or the [magic database](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) isn't always available I though of using the type `index` associated with each file on the [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobal.

So my question is, where does this index come from? I suspect it either comes from the browser (and if that's the case it can be forged) or, most likely, from the web server (or PHP) - and if this is the case: is it just an extension to mime type mapping or is it the real thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the MIME type of the file supplied by the browser through interpreting the extension of the file. So you're right, this can be forged by the client.

Comment: +1 See [the relevant manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: @lonesomeday: Thank you, I was looking for that page.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your question but [@BoldClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) has already supplied that.

Firstly i would not use this to validate your files, its not 100% reliable, instead I would scan the file for its [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) using file functions and some binary conversions functions.

It may sound complex but its not really that hard.

Every file should have a set of magic numbers that allow you to deter the file type by reading the first 4 / 8 / 16 bytes of data.

> PDF files start with "%PDF" (hex 25 50 44 46).

You would have to implement other checks as well, for example: Microsoft Office PPT / DOC / XLS all have the same bytecode so you would also validate the extension aswell.

Remember safety first.

Comment: That's good to know. What happens if, for instance a `.php` file has the following content: `%PDF<?php destroyServer(); ?>`?

Comment: Alix, That's not how it works, The data is binary and written to the header of the files, there not visible as content.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined by the client when it constructs the POST request. Files can only be present with a [multipart/form-data body](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html), which looks like that:

```
--BoUnDaRy02984
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="textfield1"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Joe owes =80100.
 --BoUnDaRy02984
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="C:\tmp\file.doc"
Content-Type: application/ms-word
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Length: 32

VGhpcyB3b3VsZCBiZSB0aGUgdGV4dAo=
 --BoUnDaRy02984
```

PHP does not interpret all possible variations of multipart/, but it detects file uploads by the presence of  a `filename=` attribute and uses the `Content-Type:` field verbatim for $_FILES[*][type].